# Files not loading on php file

Tags: php, html, css, image, layout

I'm having a few problems when I upload my design to my hosting.
Sometimes different things won't load css files, images, jsfiles, etc.
This makes it so my design looks like this. I've checked all my file paths, and they all are correct.

Sometimes my index.php won't even load.

[Here's a preview.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uo9t.png)

[Here's another preview when I refresh.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZhWU.png)

Thank you for the help.

Comment: path may be correct but probably you miss to upload the resources you are linking

Comment: There's probably a problem with the paths. Look int he page's source code to see what paths are used. Often, the mistake is using a relative path: `images/` instead of an absolute one: `/images/`

Comment: @LelioFaieta The paths aren't the problem, everything loads, but not always, sometimes my .php or .css files won't even load

Comment: Open up dev tools and it should report in the console what resources couldn't be reached to narrow it down, who is your host?

Comment: @LeoFNaN sometimes my index.php won't even load, so I don't think the paths are a problem.

Comment: your site url man?

Comment: http://sophisticated.axeldrp147.147.axc.nl/index.php sorry, i have to have 10 reputation to include more than 2 links @MasivuyeCokile

Comment: @AxelD'Olislager Page Not found

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile That's the problem, sometimes this loads, sometimes it doesn't. I have to refresh a couple of times to get it working for one time

Comment: I see its now loading

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile could this be a problem with the provider? Or does it have to do something with my files?

Comment: @AxelD'Olislager <div class="left">
                <img class="logo" src="#" alt="SOPHISTICATEDBRAND LOGO">
            </div>

Logo you did not specify the source of the image

Comment: You also have three errors on the console check your file paths

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I know that is the case, but that wouldn't be the problem from my file not loading, would it? I've removed that image and I'm still having problems loading some files and sometimes the whole index.php file itself.

Comment: The problem might be the host, I'm visiting their website but unfortunately I don't understand dutch

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile That's the problem. They are uploaded, but sometimes just won't load.

Comment: what happens when you working on your local host?

Comment: Everything loads perfectly. It's really weird.

Comment: you using windows hosting or linux hosting? do you have any .htaccess files on your home directory?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I have no idea. I'm using webhost versio.nl, they don't say anything about the type of hosting that they're using(as in serversoftware).

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I have contacted my serverhost. They've restarted their servers and everything is working now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have contacted my website hosting. They have restarted the server and everything is working now.

The problem would have been that there were 2 servers running on one or something they said. I have no idea what they were talking about. But it helped!

Thanks to everyone who helped out!

Comment: Great that you found solution, was gonna say change web host

Answer (score 0):

If you have Linux Hosting, then the references for css, images, javascript files must have the same exact name. It is case sensitive.
E.g., Style.css is different than style.css and style.CSS for Linux hosting hence it will not load those files and will give file not found error.

And it applies to folder names as well. E.g. if logo.jpg is in a folder named "Images" then reference should have "../Images/logo.jpg". And if you have "../images/logo.jpg" then you get "File not found".

Comment: I use uppercase foldernames, could this also be a problem? These are also linked as uppercase in the paths

Comment: Yes. folder names should be exactly the same as they have their names physically. Please see edited answer.

Comment: I have done this, and this is still the case, here's a link to the webpage

Comment: Do you have all of these folders' names in uppercase?

Comment: yes they do. Normaly all my paths are linked correctly but my index.php won't load sometimes aswell.

Comment: Yes i did, check my last answer.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Use Xampp
www.apachefriends.org/de/download.html
But if you do, download the version 5.5.38, it works better than the new version.

After installing, close applications that need Port 80, start the Apache, and pull your folder with your stuff in "C:\xampp\htdocs". 

localhost/"yourfilename" is the domain you could use it.

Option 2: Use a virtual machine and install a linux server.
 [Virtual Machine Download](http://www.chip.de/downloads/VMware-Player-Workstation_12994646.html) 
[Ubuntu Server Download](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server)
Now  you can install your Server and open it.

Comment: This irrelevant. I'm using a webhost.

Comment: didnt know this. Maybe its a jquery fail or you missed something in your <head> tag.